# Requires extended permission on facebook for send notification

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am new in developing Facebook App. When i am trying to send user notification and test sent notification on **Graph API Explorer** ,I am getting this error **(#200) Requires extended permission: manage_notifications** .

Comment: Post some code. We can't help you find your problem if you don't show what you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the '*manage_notifications*' scope in the facebook link connection you launch.

If not, it may be required the review of your app by Facebook to use that scope (*manage_notifications*) without issues.

Comment: there is no option to add  manage_notifications when i am click on get user access token

Comment: Do you use the api version  2.3 or previous? Because the _mange_notification_ permission is deprecated in newer versions.Take a look to this info: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-manage_notifications)

Comment: I am using 2.6 version

Comment: In that case, @SAR you cannot use manage_notification permission. Take a look to the link I posted in my previous comment.